# Set a tab as active in material ui tab component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tabs, material-ui

i'm using material ui as the mandatory library for the current
project. A page of a project requires four tabs, so I'm using the tab component from material ui library.

When I'm rendering the page which contains the tabs by default the first tab is the active tab. I want  to set the fourth tab as active.

From the documentation, I see the "**value**" prop of the Tab. So I set the values of my four tabs to 1,2,3 and 4 for each Tab respectively. When Inavigate to the respective screen , i dispatch an action which is set property tab value in my store as 4.

Then though mapStateToProps i'm made this property accessible to my component. So the value when I enter the page is four but still the active Tab is the first one. Let me show you my code:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
   value: state.get('tabValue');
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
 tabClicked: () => setActiveTab('tabValue', 4)
})
```

And my component:

```
const Tabs = ({ value }) => (
 <Tabs>
   <Tab value={1}></Tab>
   ....
   <Tab value={value}</Tab>
 </Tabs
```

)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For you to select a different tab by default use initialSelectedIndex.

For older versions of material ui, it will be of the form

```
<Tabs initialSelectedIndex={value}>
   <Tab value={1}></Tab>
   ...
  <Tab value={4}></Tab>
</Tabs>
```

For newer versions >4

```
<Tabs value={value}>
  <Tab label="Tab1" />
  <Tab label="Tab2" />
  <Tab label="Tab3" />
</Tabs>
```

Check https://material-ui.com/components/tabs/

Comment: This property doesn't exist in the current version https://material-ui.com/api/tabs/ (even the link is changed)

Comment: Fixed the answer @Fogus

Answer (score 2):

As of the latest version of material UI today (`4.1`) , set the default active tab through the property `value` defined at `Tabs`. Sample code below opens `Tab 2` as default:

```
<Tabs value={1}>
        <Tab label="Tab 1"  {...a11yProps(0)} />
        <Tab  label="Tab 2" {...a11yProps(1)} />
 </Tabs>
  <TabPanel value={0} index={0}>
        Item One
  </TabPanel>
  <TabPanel value={1} index={1}>
        Item Two
  </TabPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

according to [MUI `Tabs` Doc](https://material-ui.com/api/tabs/) you have to add `value` attr in `<Tabs>` for

> The value of the currently selected `Tab`. If you don't want any selected `Tab`, you can set this property to `false`.

and according to [MUI `Tab` Doc](https://material-ui.com/api/tab/) you have to add `value` attr in `<Tab>` for

> You can provide your own value. Otherwise, we fallback to the child position index.

code example:

```js
const Tabs = ({ value }) => (
 <Tabs value={value}>
   <Tab value={1}></Tab>
   ....
   <Tab value={value}</Tab>
 </Tabs>
)
```

both `value` in `Tabs` and `Tab` must be in the same type

Answer (score 0):

You can use the state to set the initial tab select.

```
const [value, setValue] = React.useState(2);

  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };
```

https://material-ui.com/components/tabs/